# Best Practice to open a New Window in MVVM Light with Parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I am fairly new to mvvm and mvvm light, but I think I understand the general idea of it. What I don't understand is if I want to open a new window, but that window needs data from the caller what is the best practice to get that data to the new window? If I pass the data to the constructor then that means I need code in the code behind to pass it to the view model. I can't use messaging, because it isn't basic data.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect this from the ancient past, but what to you mean by " I can't use messaging, because it isn't basic data." ? I'm asking this because I'm learning MVVM and if I was in your situation I would use Messaging.

Comment: I'm sorry it has been too long for me to remember

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One popular choice is to use a service class that will create a view/viewmodel and display the new view.  Your view model constructor and/or method/property could receive the data from the caller and then the view would be bound to the viewmodel prior to displaying it on the screen.

here is a very very simple implementation of a DialogService:

```
public class DialogService : IDisposable
{
    #region Member Variables
    private static volatile DialogService instance;
    private static object syncroot = new object();
    #endregion

    #region Ctr
    private DialogService()
    {

    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Methods
    public void ShowDialog(object _callerContentOne, object _callerContentTwo)
    {
        MyDialogViewModel viewmodel = new MyDialogViewModel(_callerContentOne, _callerContentTwo);
        MyDialogView view = new MyDialogView();
        view.DataContext = viewmodel;

        view.ShowDialog();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    #endregion

    #region Properties
    public DialogService Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncroot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                    {
                        instance = new DialogService();
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: would you please show me a basic example? I'm not sure I follow you completely.

Comment: geedubb that only works for silverlight. I am building a wpf application on visual studio 2010.

Comment: Actually, that is not a Silverlight-only solution geedbubb posted.  It may be tailored for Silverlight, but Silverlight and WPF are very very similar.  The idea is to learn from the techniques implemented in that link and then tailor it for your own personal solution.